# this procedure basically gets a sentence of the user and the splits it up into its position values and writes them to a file

Tags: python, performance

this program does  work entirely without any errors appearing however I would like to shorten it down to make it more reliable and neat

```
    def compress_sentence():
        sentence_to_be_compressed, output_file_name, position_file_name =  input('what sentance would you like to compress?').split(), input('what would you like to name the output file?') + '.txt', input('What would you like to name the posistion value') + '.txt'
        position_value, output, dictionary, words = " ", " ", {}, " "
        for position_value, word in enumerate(sentence_to_be_compressed):
            if word not in dictionary:
                dictionary[word] = position_value + 1
                output = output + str(dictionary[word]) + " "
        fu = open(output_file_name, "w")
        fu.write(output)
        fu.close()
        fi = open(position_file_name, "w")
        for word in dictionary:
            words = word + " " + str(dictionary[word]) + " "
            fi.write(words)
            fi.close()
        for line in open(position_file_name, "r").readlines(): print(line)
            print(output)
```

Comment: You don't want to shorten code. You want to improve it's readability.

Comment: "How to shorten this" is a poor title for this site — nearly every question wants shorter code. Instead, tell us what you are trying to achieve, and make that your title. Add some example input and output. See [ask].

Comment: This also looks very similar to your [previous question](/q/125312/9357).  Are you merely seeking clarification on those answers?

Comment: it does something similar to the last one however I haven't found anything on how to shorten a nested for and if loop onto one line.  as you can see i have made a one line for loop towards the bottom  however i want to make that at the top as well.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions I can make:

- **Break down your code into smaller, self-contained functions.**

  Your function is doing at least three things: asking the user for input, processing that input, and writing that input to disk. It would be better to break this down into several different functions:

  - Ask the user for input – which sentence do they want to compress, where to save, etc.
  - Do the processing, and return the result as a pure Python object
  - Write the result of that function to a file

  Breaking down the code into smaller functions like this makes it easier to reuse code – for example, if I want to do the initial processing, then do some extra work, I can call the second function directly without having to unpick the other code.
- **Use `with open(…)` instead of `open() … close()`.**

  This means that if you throw an error while you have the file open, it will be closed correctly, and won’t be left dangling open. It also means you can’t forget to write the `close()` statement, and often results in shorter code. For example, compare:

  ```
  fu = open(output_file_name, "w")
  fu.write(output)
  fu.close()
  ```

  with:

  ```
  with open(output_file_name, 'w') as fu:
      fu.write(output)
  ```

  I’m also a bit suspicious of the `fi` file – won’t you close it on every iteration of the `for word in dictionary` loop? Which means it won’t be open for subsequent iterations.
- **Make use of the dict.items() method.**

  Speaking of that loop, you can make it neater by iteration over the (key, value) pairs directly, rather than iterating over the keys, then looking up the values later.

  ```
  for word, value in dictionary.items():
      words = word + ' ' + str(value) + ' '
      fi.write(words)
  ```
- **Don’t cram so much onto a single line.**

  The first two lines of the function have three and four variable assignments per line, respectively. *That’s too many.* Readability is very important, and it would be better to have one assignment per line, than cram them all together. It just makes the code messy and harder to read.